# span doesn't apply css style when entered via innerHTML

Tags: html, css, angular, innerhtml, angular-pipe

I have and Angular app, and as part of it I show query result in a div (has ID of JSONContainer).

I wanted to highlight the specific query inside the result, so I used a pipe that searchs the results, and replaces the FIELD:VALUE in the text with:

```
<span class="highlightSpan">FIELD:VALUE</span>.
```

I added the following css to the component:

```
div#JSONContainer span.highlightSpan{
    background-color: rgba(28, 243, 28, 0.5) !important;
    color:red !important;
    padding: 1px;
    margin:1px;
}
```

I tried adding the same style under .highlightSpan as well, with the same results.

I insert this span and the rest of the text via innerHTML in the containing component, using the 'data' variable, that stores the entire JSON, and 'query' variable that stores the query:

```
    <div class="col-xs-12" id="JSONContainer"
        [innerHTML]="data | textHighlight:query">
    </div>
```

(I'm not using string interpolation because the data var is json shaped which I styled using html code,like html br tag, and string interpolation shows only text).

When I point my mouse to the relevent span in google dev tools, I see that the span with the class was created:

[image: span]

But the css style is not applyed, and its not even showing in google dev tools:

[image]

EDIT: I know it dosen't show (I erased it from the img), but the span is located in the div#JSONContainr, as described.

EDIT 2:
Here is the relevant tree:

[image]

Why is this happening?

How to make the css style apply?

Thanks!

Comment: Is that span actually located inside `div#JSONContainer` inside the final DOM? We can’t tell that from your screenshot, only that the immediate parent is something different.

Comment: Can you provide example HTML that is generated?

Comment: Doesn't look like your span is inside `div#JSONContainer` or you have multiple `#JSONContainer` (duplicated id's)

Comment: where's your id #JSONContainer located?

Comment: Hi everyone, I earased the html tree from the google dev screenshot, for privacy reasons, but the span is in the jsonContainer, as described. Also, I don't think that any other style apply, because google dev dosen't show the hightlight style overruled, it doesn't show them at all @Justinas.

Comment: Can you try by adding css properties "display: inline-block"? Sometimes its omit with inline element.

Comment: @Hanif, I tried, no effect. Again, it seems that no style is applied.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This happens because you are adding the `span` element dynamically and it is not part of your component, therefore the `span` element is not decorated with component style isolation. When you explore your components rendered html then you see that each element has attribute like `_ngcontent-c2` but your span doesn't, so it is not part of that component styling.

You can change your css to:

`::ng-deep div#JSONContainer span.highlightSpan`

to style descendants of your component (other components or elements added dynamically). Or you can add the styling to your global style so it is not part of that component isolation.

I have created [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cqaksb) to simulate your situation.

You can read more about [angular view encapsulation](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-host-context/).

Comment: try `::ng-deep div#JSONContainer .span.highlightSpan`

Comment: I tried, still not it. I don't understand why the style doesn't even appear in google dev tools.

Comment: Updated demo to be closer to your situation. What version of angular are you using? When `::ng-deep` doesn't work for you then move the styling to global `styles.css`

Comment: I use angular 6.
What do you mean adding to global css? with what syntax?

Comment: :: ng deep work at last, just needed to fix the typo and remove the dot before "span". Thanks!

Comment: cool, didn't notice that dot either, edited answer. the demo was without the dot though ;). With global styles i meant that you could move `div#JSONContainer span.highlightSpan` to `styles.css` and it would work, just maybe the selector could be simpler, like `.highlight`

Comment: For me, using the ::ng-deep solution worked very well

Answer (score 1):

In your PIPE you have to import

```
import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml } from '@angular/platform-browser';
```

Add to constructor

```
  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
  }
```

In transform function return

```
this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml('YOUR HTML');
```

Comment: Hi. I get and error that tells me that bypassSecurity function is only used when there are <script> tags, and I don't have one in my text. Plus, I don't like the idea that I open my app to XSS attacks.

Comment: Other reason if your css style is in the component, try to move it in global css file.

Comment: The above comment (using the global css file, ex. styles.scss) is absolutely the best solution. You don't need to bypass the dom sanitizer,  there is no need to set encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation to None in the component decorator and you can still use [innerHtml|="article" to render the html received from your cms. You can add a <div class="cms-article-content"> wrapper around the rendered html to select specific css.