# How to style nested <sup> element?

Tags: html, css, angular

I have an html element in my angular app that looks like

```
<p class="headline" [innerHTML]="content.headline"></p>
```

And `content.headline` is `"<sup>$</sup>425MM"`.
I want to apply specific styling to the `sup` element.

In my css file, I have tried:

```
.headline sup {
    color: red !important;
}

sup {
    color: red !important;
}

.headline > sup {
    color: red !important;
}

p sup {
    color: red !important;
}

p > sup {
    color: red !important;
}
```

None of these work. What am I doing wrong? How can I achieve this styling?

Comment: This looks wrong - `<p class="headline" [innerHTML]="content.headline"></p>` should that not be `<p class="headline"> [innerHTML]="content.headline"</p>`?

Comment: see this answer for ref
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41979458/how-to-get-angular2-innerhtml-to-work

Comment: Why use innerHTML in the first place?

Comment: [Might be useful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52969833/span-doesnt-apply-css-style-when-entered-via-innerhtml) along with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36265026/angular-2-innerhtml-styling).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [this so post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52969833/span-doesnt-apply-css-style-when-entered-via-innerhtml) shared by Nicholas K, I got an answer

```
::ng-deep sup {
    color: red !important;
}
```

Comment: Except it is deprecated, as stated in Angular docs : https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep. You could import global css or use ViewEncapsulation.None.